# Size of container elements adjusting to header word lenght - how to fix it? (absolute begginer)

Tags: html, css

i just started coding (two days ago) and was following Dev Ed's glass webpage tutorial.

Since i just started i don't know if i'll be able to say correctly what i mean so i'll show the examples

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Gcq.png)

How could I make the elements within that container independant from the header lenght? I want to keep the other elements with its regular size

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to left top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
  );
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
             <div class="card">
              <img src="/images/assassins.png" alt="" />
              <div class="card-info">
                <h2>Assassins Creed Valhalla</h2>
                <p>PS5 Version</p>
                <div class="progress"></div>
              </div>
              <h2 class="percentage">60%</h2>
            </div>
              <div class="card">
               <img src="/images/sackboy.png" alt="" />
               <div class="card-info">
                <span><h2>Sackboy </h2></span>
                 <p>PS5 Version</p>
                 <div class="progress"></div>
               </div>
               <h2 class="percentage">60%</h2>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: 1` to `.card-info`

`flex` is a property only available if the element *is* a child of a container that has `display: flex`. It basically tells the element to increase in width as much as it can before it hits another element. IT's also shorthand for `flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis`.

See here for more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

As you're new to coding, it would be best to learn the more verbose methods (flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis) before using shorthand.

Additionally adding `width: 100%` would also achieve the same result but could cause issues if you added `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container.

Also welcome to coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add "Flex: 1" to the card.info. What Flex:1 is is simply make the width of the element independent of the width of the parent element

I'm not sure if this is the thing that you want to achieve because the snippet if a lot different than the picture shown.